# Understanding weird branch merge with git

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch

I'm working on a remote branch named sidebar, created like this (from my pc, not remote repo) :

```
$ git branch sidebar
$ git checkout sidebar
$ git push -u origin sidebar
$ git pull origin sidebar
```

After some commit on the sidebar branch i pushed it to the repo :

```
$ git push origin sidebar
```

Now it seems sidebar is merged to master and i don't understand why :

```
$ git log --graph

* commit 3830b6e72f4249cd15c7a35e47a2
| Author: me
| Date:   Mon Apr 30 16:56:28 2012 +0200
| 
|     re-build sidebar boxes
|    
*   commit e97e63b05a522e29d3ca97a509e3652d
|\  Merge: eb1ebfd ed10585
| | Author: me
| | Date:   Sat Apr 28 15:54:19 2012 +0200
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'master' of 
| |   
| * commit 6495e5bd7ac12364a4a12389f58
| | Author: misterX
| | Date:   Sat Apr 28 03:46:58 2012 +0200
| | 
| |     FB: add friend list with statistics
| |   
* | commit eb89c0bbb5516b1ed795b9fc958
|/  Author: me
|   Date:   Sat Apr 28 15:54:08 2012 +0200
|   
|       add product img lens icon
```

Do you know what happened and where am i wrong ?

EDIT: Maybe the following could help

```
$ git remote show origin
Password: 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: user@repo
  Push  URL: user@repo
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master  tracked
    sidebar tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master  merges with remote master
    sidebar merges with remote sidebar
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master  pushes to master  (local out of date)
    sidebar pushes to sidebar (fast-forwardable)
```

Comment: Look like instead of `$ git pull origin sidebar` you did `$ git pull origin master` which is essentially "fetch the master and merge it into the current branch".

Comment: I already checked it. My bash history say `git pull origin sidebar`, no master

Comment: You know, technically if someone forcibly replaced branch "sidebar" in the remote repo with the "master" and then reverted it back you could, in theory, get this-looking history if you happened to pull from that "sidebar" branch while it was replaced. But the name "master" is written in the commit message so it really was "master", and not something else. I'm not stating it's necessarily you who merged master but Git's hashing of commits makes certain things certain. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm trying to understand why this happened. I edited my post. Maybe could help ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this adds nothing of interest to the picture: 1) you have pretty standard push/pull setup; 2) remote has more commits on master than you do; 3) you have some commits on sidebar which remote does not, but no one messed with sidebar remotely so would you push sidebar now, that would result in fast-forward.

Answer (score 0):

That gitlog suggests the following happened:

- Author misterX did a commit (on Sat Apr 28 03:46:58 2012 +0200) and pushed it *after* your last pull before commit eb89c0bbb5516b1ed795b9fc958 (Sat Apr 28 15:54:08 2012 +0200). This caused a fork, since both your commit and the one from misterX are based on the commit before that
- You did a `git pull` within eleven seconds after your commit. Git is pretty clever and at this point noticed that your local head of the sidebar branch differed by the remote sidebar head in only one commit and, due to no merge conflicts occurring, silently merged the commits. This is perfectly normal behaviour, except for the message claiming this happened on the branch master. Either the version of git you use has a bug there, or you accidentally switched to master via `git checkout master` at some point - check the output of `git branch`

On a side node, if you don't want this merging behaviour, you can use `git pull --rebase` instead, which will attempt to rebase all your commits on top of the ones pushed by others since your last pull. History will look cleaner that way, though the commit dates may then suggest someone time-travelled...